# 100% width and height image before the rest of the content

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to achieve an effect such as this one seen f.e. here: http://www.createpilates.com/

What I'm trying to do is to have a "cover" image as the website loads and then if users scrolls down, content is visible.

Notice that the first image always covers 100% of the loaded screen, no matter if I resize the window, etc.

Can somebody help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your element has its full height and width set, then you use something like this:

```
#element {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("yourimage.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="yourimage.jpg", sizingMethod="scale"); 
}
```